# Is this a valid asymptotic approximation to $\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(kn)}{1+k^2}dk$?

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics

I want to obtain an asymptotic expansion for $\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(kn)}{1+k^2}dk$ in which $n\to \infty$.

Per Gary's suggestion, examine https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.11#i

I do not understand where the trigonmetric terms go when $m\to \infty$ yielding their $(2.11.2)$ series. How is that series obtained?

Comment: What if $n$ is an integer?

Comment: Then it's zero.

Comment: Note that something like $f(x)\sim 0$ is meaningless. Anyway, consider https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.11.i

Comment: Can you please explain how the series they write is obtained from integration by parts?

Comment: It would be easier to do so if you undeleted the question.

Comment: @robjohn Done. I deleted because I had worked it out myself. Per Olver "ASymptotics and special functions" page 75, the even terms of the approximation disappear because they are imaginary. The trigonometric terms are evaluated on $\pi$ and $0$.

Comment: If could comment about the error that would be helpful for me

Comment: In my answer, I did not assume $n$ was an integer, as it seems the two newer answers do. Although $n$ was not stated to be an integer in the question, did you intend it to be?

Comment: The $m$ in $(2.11.2)$ is evidently assumed to be an integer. At the end of my answer, the absence of $\sin$ and $\cos$ is discussed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrating by parts $4$ times:
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(nx)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac1n\int_0^\pi\frac1{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}\sin(nx)\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac1n\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{1+\pi^2}+\frac2n\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin(nx)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1c}\\
&=\frac1n\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{1+\pi^2}-\frac2{n^2}\int_0^\pi\frac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}\cos(nx)\tag{1d}\\
&=\frac1n\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{1+\pi^2}-\frac2{n^2}\frac{\pi\cos(n\pi)}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^2}+\frac2{n^2}\int_0^\pi\frac{1-3x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^3}\cos(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1e}\\
&=\frac1n\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{1+\pi^2}-\frac2{n^2}\frac{\pi\cos(n\pi)}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^2}+\frac2{n^3}\int_0^\pi\frac{1-3x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^3}\,\mathrm{d}\sin(nx)\tag{1f}\\
&=\scriptsize\frac1n\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{1+\pi^2}-\frac2{n^2}\frac{\pi\cos(n\pi)}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^2}+\frac2{n^3}\frac{1-3\pi^2}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^3}\sin(n\pi)+\frac{24}{n^3}\int_0^\pi\frac{x\left(1-x^2\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^4}\sin(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1g}\\
&=\scriptsize\frac1n\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{1+\pi^2}-\frac2{n^2}\frac{\pi\cos(n\pi)}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^2}+\frac2{n^3}\frac{1-3\pi^2}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^3}\sin(n\pi)-\frac{24}{n^4}\int_0^\pi\frac{x\left(1-x^2\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^4}\,\mathrm{d}\cos(nx)\tag{1h}\\
&=\scriptsize\frac1n\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{1+\pi^2}-\frac2{n^2}\frac{\pi\cos(n\pi)}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^2}+\frac2{n^3}\frac{1-3\pi^2}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^3}\sin(n\pi)-\frac{24}{n^4}\frac{\pi\left(1-\pi^2\right)}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^4}\cos(n\pi)\\
&+\frac{24}{n^4}\int_0^\pi\frac{1-10 x^2+5x^4}{\left(1+x^2\right)^5}\cos(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1i}\\
\end{align}
$$
The total variation of $\frac{1-10 x^2+5x^4}{\left(1+x^2\right)^5}$ on $[0,\pi]$ is bounded by $\frac{59}{32}$; $f(0)=1,f\!\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)=-\frac{27}{64},f(\pi)\approx0$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\,\frac{24}{n^4}\int_0^\pi\frac{1-10 x^2+5x^4}{\left(1+x^2\right)^5}\cos(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\tag{2a}\\
&=\left|\,\frac{24}{n^5}\int_0^\pi\frac{1-10 x^2+5x^4}{\left(1+x^2\right)^5}\,\mathrm{d}\sin(nx)\,\right|\tag{2b}\\
&=\left|\,\frac{24}{n^5}\frac{1-10\pi^2+5\pi^4}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^5}-\frac{24}{n^5}\int_0^\pi\sin(nx)\,\mathrm{d}\frac{1-10 x^2+5x^4}{\left(1+x^2\right)^5}\,\right|\tag{2c}\\
&\le\frac{24}{n^5}\left(\frac{1-10\pi^2+5\pi^4}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^5}+\frac{59}{32}\right)\tag{2d}\\
&\lt\frac{45}{n^5}\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we get the asymptotic expansion of $\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(nx)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ to be
$$
\frac1n\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{1+\pi^2}-\frac2{n^2}\frac{\pi\cos(n\pi)}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^2}+\frac2{n^3}\frac{1-3\pi^2}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^3}\sin(n\pi)-\frac{24}{n^4}\frac{\pi\left(1-\pi^2\right)}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)^4}\cos(n\pi)\tag3
$$
with an error smaller than $\frac{45}{n^5}$.

If $n$ is an integer, then $\sin(n\pi)=0$ and $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$, which accounts for any missing $\sin$’s and $\cos$’s.

Comment: At around $n=5$, the error is about $73.5\%$ of $\frac{45}{n^5}$. For larger $n$, the bound given above is much larger than the actual error.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. What was the motivation for performing IBP until the fourth iteration? Why not stop at, say, the third?

Comment: I just thought that two sine and two cosine terms seemed reasonable, and it gives a good idea of how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

Start writing
$$\frac{\cos (k n)}{k^2+1}=\frac{\cos (k n)}{(k+i)(k-i)}=\frac i 2\left(\frac{\cos (k n)}{k+i}-\frac{\cos (k n)}{k-i} \right)$$

Let $k+i=x$

$$\int\frac{\cos (k n)}{k+i}\,dk=\int \frac{\cos (n (x-i))}{x}\,dx$$

Expand the cosine to face the sine and cosine integrals.

For the deinite integral, you should end with
$$2\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos (k n)}{k^2+1}\,dk=
(\text{Si}(i n-n \pi )-\text{Si}(n (i+\pi ))) \sinh (n)-i
   (\text{Ci}(-n (-i+\pi ))-\text{Ci}(n (i+\pi ))) \cosh (n)$$

Assuming that $n$ is an integer
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos (k n)}{k^2+1}\,dk=\frac \pi 2 \left(e^{-n}-4(-1)^n  A\right)$$where
$$A=\frac{1}{\left(1+\pi ^2\right)^2 n^2}-\frac{12 \left(\pi ^2-1\right)}{\left(1+\pi ^2\right)^4 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$

**Edit**

If $n$ is not an integer
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos (k n)}{k^2+1}\,dk=\frac{\pi  e^{-n}}{2}+\frac{A \cos(n\pi)+B \sin(n\pi)}{\left(1+\pi ^2\right)^4 n^4}$$ where
$$A=-2 \pi  \left(\left(1+\pi ^2\right)^2 n^2-12 \left(\pi
   ^2-1\right)\right)$$
$$B=\left(1+\pi ^2\right) n \left(\left(1+\pi ^2\right)^2 n^2-6 \pi   ^2+2\right)$$

Comment: (+1) Since the question uses $k$ as a real variable, I did not assume that $n$ was an integer. However, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, I believe our answers agree.

Comment: @robjohn. I assumed it was. It makes life easier. AT m'y age' I am Always surprized bye thé number off approches for thé same problème. Sorry for typos : m'y wife IS note présent to reread. Thanks and cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that $n$ is a positive integer. From Section $6.2$ on page $77$ of F. W. J. Olver's book *Asymptotics and Special Functions*, we obtain
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(nt)}{1+t^2}\mathrm{d}t=
\frac{\pi }{2}{\rm e}^{ - n}  + ( - 1)^n \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {( - 1)^k \frac{{q^{(2k + 1)} (\pi )}}{{n^{2k + 2} }}}  + R_N (n)\tag{1}$$
for any $N\ge 1$, with
$$
\left| {R_N (n)} \right| \le \frac{1}{{n^{2N + 1} }}\int_\pi ^{ + \infty } {\left| {q^{(2N + 1)} (t)} \right|{\rm d}t}.
$$
Here $q(t)=(1+t^2)^{-1}$. It is not difficult to show that
$$
q^{(2k + 1)} (t) = -\frac{{(2k + 1)!}}{{(1 + t^2 )^{k + 1} }}\sin \left( {(2k + 2)\arcsin \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + t^2 } }}} \right)} \right),
$$
whence
\begin{align*}
\left| {R_N (n)} \right| & \le \frac{{(2N + 1)!}}{{n^{2N + 1} }}\int_\pi ^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\rm d}t}{{(1 + t^2 )^{N+ 1} }}} \\ &  = \frac{1}{2}\frac{{(2N + 1)!}}{{n^{2N + 1} }}\int_{\log (1 + \pi ^2 )}^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - Ns} \frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{\sqrt {{\rm e}^s  - 1} }}}  \\ & \le \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\frac{{(2N + 1)!}}{{n^{2N + 1} }}\int_{\log (1 + \pi ^2 )}^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - Ns} {\rm d}s} \\ & = \frac{1}{{2\pi N}}\frac{{(2N + 1)!}}{{(1 + \pi ^2 )^N n^{2N + 1} }}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Using the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind,
\begin{align*}
q^{(2k + 1)} (t) & = -\frac{{(2k + 1)!}}{{(1 + t^2 )^{k + 1} }}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + t^2 } }}U_{2k + 1} \!\left( {\frac{t}{{\sqrt {1 + t^2 } }}} \right)
\\ & = ( - 1)^{k+1} \frac{{(2k + 1)!}}{{(1 + t^2 )^{2k + 2} }}\sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {( - 1)^j \binom{2k + 2}{2j + 1}t^{2j + 1} } .
\end{align*}
This formula provides an explicit expression for the coefficients of the expansion $(1)$.

By Stirling's formula and the bound $(2)$, it may be shown that with the choice $N = \left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor$, $R_N (n)= \mathcal{O}(n^{ - 1/2} (\sqrt {1 + \pi ^2 } {\rm e})^{ - n})$.

Comment: Where does your $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-n}$ term come from? Equation $(6.01)$ from the book does not have that.

Comment: Please read my second sentence again more carefully.

Comment: From a numerical point of view, this is a much better way to approximate the integral. If you do the estimate for the error of the expansion in Section 6.1 instead, you will find that it is much larger.